# Easy way to work with keyboard input?

Tags: c++, input

I'm making a simple program using the graphic mode in C++, I'm having trouble dealing with the input.
I just need a way to check the keyboard and, if any key has been pressed, store the key value on a variable,
the problem with `getch()` is that it waits untill any key has been pressed, and I need the programm to keep going if the user is not giving input.
I've made a research and it seems that there are hundreds of ways of doing this.
which one is the easiest?

*Example:* the loop begins, the program checks if there has been any input and stores it, the program works with that input and then discards it to begin the loop again. That would work perfectly with `getch()` isn't it? Well I want the loop to also keep going if no key has been pressed this time. A sort of no input default mode so the process doesn't stop.

(what I would really like is an equivalent to `getch()` that does'nt wait for user input).

Windows, Code::Blocks IDE, GCC compiler

yeah, kbhit seems to work as expected, Thanks!!

Comment: On which operating system? If on Linux, consider [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)... see also [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). And please edit your question and tags to explain more.

Comment: What is "the graphic mode in C++"?

Comment: @PIXEL: C++ doesn't have a "graphic mode", nor a `graphics.h`. Presumably you're using some library, then. Did you try `#include "solution_for_my_problem.h"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `int _kbhit( void );` : it's a non-blocking call to `getch()`(works only on Windows).
It's also included in `conio.h`

Doc here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/58w7c94c.aspx

(There is also a workaround for *nix systems : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/63166-kbhit-linux.html )

Comment: Eh? There's absolutely nothing "ISO" about `_kbhit`. The leading underscore and the `conio.h` are both clues, as is the need for a "workaround" under Linux.

Comment: sorry, i've just copied from this page :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms235390.aspx . According to MSDN, it's ISO conformant.

Comment: \*shrug\* Maybe they mean it can be implemented in a conformant manner; I don't know. But grep the C++ standard for `_kbhit` and you'll see it's not there. If it were, it would be _more_ likely to be available on Linux, not less. *`conio.h` is not a standard header. It is a Microsoft header.*

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit : just skimmed trough the ISO:2003 and there is no mentions of keyboard -or even system- inputs whatsoever. I don't know where from the MS doc's writer has pulled this one out.

Comment: He might be referring to the addition of the underscore to fit into the standard's "implementation-reserved names have leading underscores" rule, but that's a bit of a reach.